# How to combine two RDD[String]s index-wise?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working with Spark RDDs and created two idential length arrays, one is the hour of tweet, and the other is the text of a tweet.  I'm looking to combine these into one data structure (perhaps a tuple?) that I can filter by the hour and text of tweets, but I'm struggling after combining on how to perform this.

```
scala> val split_time = split_date.map(line => line.split(":")).map(word =>
(word(0)))
split_time: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[28] at map 
at <console>:31

scala> split_time.take(10)
res8: Array[String] = Array(17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17)


scala> val split_text = text.map(line => line.split(":")).map(word => 
(word(1).toLowerCase))
split_text: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[19] at map at <console>:29

scala> split_text.take(10)
res0: Array[String] = Array("add @joemontana to this pic and you've got 
something #nfl https, "are you looking for photo editor, "#colts frank gore 
needs 27 rushing yards to pass jerome bettis and 49 yards to pass ladainian 
tomlinson to move int… https, "rt @nflstreamfree,.....

# combine into tuple
val tweet_tuple = (split_time, split_text)
```

For example, I want to get all tweets for hour 17 with the word "colts" mentioned:

```
tweet_tuple.filter(tup => tup._1 == 17 && tup._2.toString.matches("colts"))

<console>:40: error: value filter is not a member of (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String], org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String])
          tweet_tuple.map(line => line._1 == 17 && line._2.toString.matches("colts"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should go with `.zip` to combine both `rdds` into `RDD[(String, String)]`

for example I created two rdds

```
val split_time = sparkContext.parallelize(Array("17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17"))
val split_text = sparkContext.parallelize(Array("17", "17", "17", "17", "colts", "17", "17", "colts", "17", "17"))
```

`zip` combines both `rdds` as I have mentioned above into `RDD[Tuple2[String, String]]`

```
val tweet_tuple = split_time.zip(split_text)
```

After combining all you need is to apply `.filter`

```
tweet_tuple.filter(line => line._1 == "17" && line._2.toString.matches("colts"))
```

The output should be

```
(17,colts)
(17,colts)
```

**Updated**

Since your `split_text` *rdd* are *collection of sentences*, `contains` should be used instead of `matches`. So the following logic should work after you've `zip`ped.

```
tweet_tuple.filter(line => line._1 == "17" && line._2.toString.contains("colts"))
```

Answer (score 1):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47707362) by [Ramesh Maharjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5880706/ramesh-maharjan) can work only under very specific assumptions:

- Both RDDs have the same number of partitions.
- Corresponding partitions have the same number of elements.

This trivial for `ParallelCollectionRDD` but it is hard or impossible to get in general.

It is much better, but costlier, to `join`:

```
split_time.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).join(
  split_text.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
).values
```

or:

```
val split_time_with_index = split_time.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
val split_text_with_index = split_text.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap) 

val partitioner = new org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner(
  split_time.getNumPartitions, split_time
)

split_time.join(split_text, partitioner)
```